# Debian 9: Is there any GUI to add OpenConnect VPN-connection in ConnMan?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, vpn, openconnect

On a lightweight Debian machine I am using `ConnMan` instead of `NetworkManager`. For this I installed `ConnMan` based on the following packages:

- `connman`
- `connman-vpn`
- `cmst`

Ethernet, wifi, virtual bridges etc. are working completely fine.

However, it seems to be impossible to graphically add a VPN-connection (`openconnect`) via `connman`'s `cmst`-GUI.

Do I have to create config-files for every VPN via text editor by hand?

---

In `NetworkManager` this was a pretty easy task within the GUI. First, install the packages

- `network-manager`
- `network-manager-gnome`
- `network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

Afterwards it was possible to set up the VPN inside the GUI.

---

In `ConnMan` this intention seems to be a bit different. So the final question now is:

**How to set up a Cisco AnyConnect compatible VPN-connection (`OpenConnect`) for use with `ConnMan`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure your VPN file you can use [`connman_dmenu`](https://github.com/march-linux/connman_dmenu):

```
# apt install suckless-tools
$ git clone https://github.com/march-linux/connman_dmenu.git
$ cd connman_dmenu
# ./connman_dmenu
```

You will be able to connect/disconnect to the configured VPN from the `cmst` GUI.

**Edit** :

`cmst` (connman-ui) have a **VPN Editor** , it can  be enabled from **Preferences** by checking **Advenced Control** , The **VPN Editor** tab will appear at the bottom of the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately `connman_dmenu` is not included in the official Debian repositories. As far as I understand this package is just a tool for creating the necessary configuration-file, right? Where do I have to put this config-file in the end? And do I need the package `openconnect` as well for running my VPN?

Comment: @Dave answer edited with the right package name.