# ConnMan: How to set up OpenConnect VPN with CSD-Wrapper correctly?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, vpn, openconnect

I want to access my personal network drive at my university via VPN from home. In the past I have been using `NetworkManager` for this what worked completely fine. However, recently I moved to `ConnMan` and I don't know very well how to set it up there.

Thanks to [GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443027/241507) I figured out there is a graphical input mask available to set up a VPN-connection in `ConnMan`'s `CMST` interface.

The previous (successfully working) VPN configuration from `NetworkManager` looked like that:

```
[openconnect]
Description=My Company
Host=vpngw2-out.net.provider.com
CACert=(null)
Protocol=anyconnect
Proxy=
CSDEnable=1
CSDWrapper=/home/user/.cisco/csd-wrapper.sh
UserCertificate=(null)
PrivateKey=(null)
FSID=0
StokenSource=disabled
StokenString=
```

---

However, this successfully working VPN config from `NetworkManager` was using a so called `CSD-wrapper` from Cisco.

The challenge in `ConnMan` now is: When creating the necessary VPN provisioning file which variant of OpenConnect do I have to select to match the upper specifications? When creating the new provisioning file via `ConnMan`-`CMST` there are several `OpenConnect`-options available:

- `Provider OpenConnect`
- `OpenConnect.ServerCert`
- `OpenConnect.CACert`
- `OpenConnect.ClientCert`
- `OpenConnect.MTU`
- `OpenConnect.Cookie`
- `OpenConnect.VPNHost`

Which one do I have to choose to match the previous configuration of the `NetworkManager` config? Do I have to mention something special to include the `CSD-Wrapper` file in `ConnMan`?

Comment: See EXAMPLES on  https://manpages.debian.org/testing/connman/connman-vpn-provider.config.5.en.html

Comment: @GAD3R: Maybe can you help me on how to set it up correctly? Unfortunately I don't understand the manpage very well... :-(

Comment: [This is an example on github](https://gist.github.com/vvavrychuk/8bf49d06e6f89db69315c7dc708acdc9). Remove NetworkManager (It is important) then create the `/var/lib/connman-vpn/name.config` file and follow the instruction.

Comment: @GAD3R: Thanks a lot for this manual! Unfortunately there is no further explanation on how to consider this ugly `CSD-Wrapper`. Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Use `--csd-wrapper` option: `openconnect --csd-wrapper=/home/user/.cisco/csd-wrapper.sh --authenticate [--user username] "VPN host"`

Comment: See the [openconnect manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/openconnect) to set all the options .

Comment: @GAD3R: Based on your great help the VPN is mostly working. Unfortunately I still receive a small error because the `COOKIE` seems to change itself all few hours and I have to create a new one with `OpenConnect` and paste its `COOKIE`-output into `/var/lib/connman-vpn/vpnname.config`. Maybe you can have a look at my posted answer below and find some mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a [comment from GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/449174/241507) and the `Connman` [developer mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/openconnect-devel@lists.infradead.org/msg00450.html), a friend figured out on how to set up the VPN connection. Although there is still a small error existent we got it work mostly.

---

**1. Initial situation**

The following packages have to be installed on your client machine from where you want to access the host server:

- `connman`
- `connman-vpn`
- `cmst`
- `openconnect`

Furthermore the script `csd-wrapper.sh` was run in your clients `/home`-directory and has created the directory `/home/.cisco` with several authentication files of your machine.

---

**2. Generating the necessary VPN authentication information by engaging `OpenConnect`**

In a second step you have to execute the `OpenConnect` authentication request to obtain the server certificate (`FINGERPRINT`) and a `COOKIE` that `Connman` will use to connect to the VPN. This information will be created by utilizing `OpenConnect` package which is later displaying a server certificate and a cookie in terminal. We generate this information in terminal by running

```
$ sudo openconnect --csd-wrapper=/home/user/.cisco/csd-wrapper.sh --authenticate --user <username> <hostname>
```

Afterwards this command will display four variables: `POST`, `COOKIE`, `HOST` and `FINGERPRINT`. Hereby the fingerprint (starting with `sha256:...`) acts as a server certificate while the `COOKIE` is what it sounds like.

---

**3. Creating the VPN provisioning file for `Connman`**

In contrast to `NetworkManager` the `Connman` is using so called VPN provisioning files for each VPN connection from where it takes the information on how to connect to the VPN host. Therefore in a third step the previously generated authentication data has to be pasted into this VPN provisioning file that `Connman` will utilize to connect to the server. To do so we create the file `/var/lib/connman-vpn/<connection-name>.config` based on the following structure:

```
[global]
Name = VPN name, for example "My Company VPN" (without quotes)

[provider_openconnect]
Type = OpenConnect
Name = VPN Provider name, for example "My Company Cisco VPN" (without quotes)
Host = <VPN host IP address>
Domain = <VPN host domain>
OpenConnect.ServerCert = <paste the output of FINGERPRINT from the previous openconnect command>
OpenConnect.Cookie = <paste the output of COOKIE from the previous openconnect command>
```

Afterwards save and close the file.

---

**4. Reboot your machine and check VPN connection**

Reboot your system and you will find your now created VPN connection listed in the rider `VPN` of Connman System Tray (`CMST`) GUI. Mark it, click on "connect" and after a few seconds the VPN-connection to your VPN-host will be established. Now you can easily access the VPN-host within the file manager of your choice.

---

**5. Eyesore: Generated cookie is only valid for a few hours**

After a few hours your previously successfully working VPN-connection won't work anymore. When checking `/var/log/syslog` the connection approach will complain about failed verification of server certificate:

```
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: ipconfig state 2 ipconfig method 1
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: vpn0 {create} index 23 type 65534 <NONE>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: vpn0 {update} flags 4240 <DOWN>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: vpn0 {newlink} index 23 address 00:00:00:00:00:00 mtu 1500
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: vpn0 {newlink} index 23 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connman-vpnd[365]: vpn0 {create} index 23 type 65534 <NONE>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connman-vpnd[365]: vpn0 {update} flags 4240 <DOWN>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connman-vpnd[365]: vpn0 {newlink} index 23 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: ipconfig state 2 ipconfig method 1
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> openconnect[4476]: Connected to <VPN server IP>:443
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> openconnect[4476]: SSL negotiation with <VPN server IP>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> openconnect[4476]: Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> openconnect[4476]: Connected to HTTPS on <VPN server IP>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> openconnect[4476]: Got inappropriate HTTP CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: vpn0 {dellink} index 23 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: (null) {remove} index 23
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connman-vpnd[365]: vpn0 {dellink} index 23 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connman-vpnd[365]: vpn0 {remove} index 23
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: ipconfig state 7 ipconfig method 1
Aug 24 00:14:51 <hostname> connmand[444]: ipconfig state 6 ipconfig method 1
```

Hereby the initial authentication-`COOKIE` has changed, so the previously generated cookie is not valid anymore. Therefore you have to repeat the upper procedure all few hours to create a new `COOKIE` and paste this new one into your VPN provisioning file (`/var/lib/connman-vpn/<yourvpnname>.config`) while overwriting the old cookie. Afterwards restart `Connman` and your VPN will work great again for the next few hours.

***Important:***

*It seems that `NetworkManager` can nudge the recreation of the new `COOKIE` by himself, while `Connman` needs to get feeded with the new `cookie` into its VPN provisioning file. Probably `Connman` is missing some kind of interface to launch the `OpenConnect`-command by himself.*

---

**6. Workaround to make recreation of the new cookie a bit more comfortable**

You can use a bash-script to generate the new cookie and overwrite the old one. Just copy the following text into a `*.sh`-file, make it executable and run it. The new cookie will be placed into `/var/lib/connman-vpn/vpnname.config` at the right position automatically. Afterwards restart `Connman` and the VPN will work fine again.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "s/^OpenConnect.Cookie =.*$/$( echo '<YOUR-VPN-PASSWORD>' | openconnect --csd-wrapper=/home/user/.cisco/csd-wrapper.sh --authenticate --user=<USERNAME> --authgroup="<YOURGROUP>" --passwd-on-stdin <VPN-HOST-DOMAIN> | grep 'COOKIE=' | sed "s/COOKIE='//; s/'//g; s/^/OpenConnect.Cookie = /")/" <EXTERNAL-FILENAME>
```

This script will:

1. Start OpenConnect and execute the `OpenConnect` authentication request to obtain the server certificate (`FINGERPRINT`) and a `COOKIE`
2. Insert your `username` into the user prompt
3. Insert your `password` into the user prompt
4. Insert your desired `group` into the user prompt
5. Generate a new `cookie`
6. Overwrite the old `cookie` in `/var/lib/connman-vpn/vpnname.config` with the new `cookie`

Afterwards you can reconnect to your VPN-host without any problems. Thanks to this script it is more comfortable and way faster to recreate new `cookies` when necessary.

Comment: @GAD3R: That would be an idea. But I am seriously wondering about the reasons for those frequent changes of the `COOKIE`. Is the `COOKIE` affected either by changes on the VPN-server or by changes on my client machine? So you think there is no other option available than replacing the old `COOKIE` with a new one in a regular time intervall of a few hours?